# Linux context switch internals: What happens when process exits before timer interrupt?

Tags: linux, scheduler, ucontext

How is context switch made in linux kernel when process exits before timer interrupt?

I know that if the process is running and timer interrupt occurs then `schedule` function is called automatically if the flag is set,  schedule function then selects next process to run. Basically in this case the schedule function runs in the context of current process but what happens when process exits even before timer interrupt? who calls `schedule` function in this case? And in what context does it run?

Comment: If you meant, what happens when a process calls `exits()`, then in this case also schedule is called.

Comment: many times process can exit without calling `exit()`.

Comment: In most of those cases - they return to the parent and it's likely they do `exit_group()` to finish things up; which also ended up being calling `schedule()`.

Comment: what do you mean by they return to parent? Parent is somewhere in your ready queue..to `return to parent` you scheduler has to schedule the parent

Comment: It's possible that you might get more informed answers over on [unix.se] if you don't get any response here.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you I will move question over there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to understand that the timer interrupt is just one of several hundred different reasons why `schedule` might get called.  Only programs whose runtime is dominated by computation, which is rarer than you'd think, ever exhaust their time slice.  It's much more common for programs to run for only a few microseconds — yes, microseconds — at a time, in between "blocking" in system calls, waiting for user input or whatever.

When a process exits in any way, ultimately a call to [`do_exit`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=4.8;i=do_exit) always happens, in the (kernel) context of that process.  `do_exit` calls [`schedule`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=schedule) as its last action, and `schedule` *never returns to that context*.  Note how, at the very end of `do_exit`, there is a call to `schedule`, followed immediately by `BUG();` and an infinite loop.

Just prior to this, `do_exit` calls `exit_notify`, which is responsible for sending `SIGCHLD` to the parent process and/or releasing it from a call to `wait`.  So, a lot of the time, the parent process will be ready-to-run when `schedule` gets called, and will be selected.

`do_exit` also deallocates all of the user-space state and much of the kernel state associated with the process, frees memory, closes file descriptors, etc.  The `task_struct` itself must survive until someone calls `wait`, and I can't figure out exactly how the kernel decides that it can now be deallocated; this code is too convoluted.

If the process called [`_exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit), the kernel call chain is simply [`sys_exit_group`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/exit.c?v=4.8#L957) to `do_group_exit` to `do_exit`.  If it took a fatal synchronous signal (e.g. `SIGSEGV`), the call chain is a lot longer and has a tricky diversion in it.  The hardware trap is fielded by architecture-specific code (e.g. x86 [`do_trap`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c?v=4.8#L231)) through `force_sig_info` and `send_signal` to [`complete_signal`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/signal.c?v=4.8#L870), which adjusts the task state and then tells the scheduler to wake up the offending process.  The offending process wakes up, and a maze of architecture-specific signal handling logic eventually delivers it to [`get_signal`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/signal.c?v=4.8#L2129), which calls `do_group_exit`, which calls `do_exit`.  Fatal *asynchronous* signals (e.g. from typing `kill 12345` at a shell prompt) start at [`sys_kill`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/signal.c?v=4.8#L2842) and go through `kill_something_info`, `group_send_sig_info`, `do_send_sig_info` to `send_signal`, after which everything proceeds as above.  In both cases, all of the steps up to `complete_signal` may happen in *any* process context, but everything after "The offending process wakes up" happens in that process's context.

The only parts of this description that are Linux-specific are the names of functions in the kernel's code.  Any implementation of Unix will have  kernel functions that do more or less what Linux's `do_exit` and `schedule` do, and the sequences of operations involved in fielding `_exit`, fatal synchronous signals, and fatal async signals will be recognizably similar.

Comment: Wow! this is what I was really looking for.. Thanks. Also if you can please add to the answer what happens when process exits unexpectedly such as segfault? do_exit won't get called in that case right?

Comment: No, in fact, `do_exit` _will_ get called if a process is killed by a signal.  I'll add some notes on that to the answer.